# Ruby on Rails Ajax Call on Wiki API returns CORS issue

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript, wikipedia-api

I'm testing out an api endpoint from wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Main%20Page&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json

using an Ajax call on Ruby on Rails. The tutorial suggests using coffeescript which is what I'm using.

```
$.ajax 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Main%20Page&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json',
type: 'GET'
format: 'json'
origin: 'https://www.mediawiki.org'
success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
    console.log(data);
```

All I'm getting is this error:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Main%20Page&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

I've researched on the issue and tried rack-cors and then configured it but so far, I'm still getting the CORS issue and not able to retrieve the api endpoint result. Can anyone help?

Comment: Im confused, you're "using a ajax call on ruby on rails" and youre calling wikipedia? That makes no sense, YOU CANNOT set the 'origin' header on javascript. If you control the server you need to add `response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'` in your ruby on rails  view.. other than that.. this is not going to work friend. Give me details and i'll help out more

Comment: I'm trying to use the wikipedia api endpoint and to do this, im implementing an ajax call to retrieve the endpoint's results. I'm not able to get the results so I've been reading on CORS functionality and one of the gems that allows this on Ruby is RACK-CORS. However, I still am not getting anything.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with this code:

```
$.ajax 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Main%20Page&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json',
type: 'GET'
dataType: 'jsonp'
origin: 'https://www.mediawiki.org'
success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
    console.log(data)
```

Adding jsonp was the thing that did it for me. I replaced format with it and got the response back from the url.